# ActionBar style as theme is ignored

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm having the following setup:

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.citylifta"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme" />
```

themes.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_button</item>
</style>
```

now, if I omit the attr `app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"`, the toolbar gets totally black...

How to define the toolbar's styling as a part of the AppTheme properly?

Comment: use xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" , and make sure you have done setSupportActionbar(toolbar) in activity

Comment: If I want to remove `app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"`, changing the `xmlns:app` doesn't make any sense

Comment: Then create custom style with proper parent and use style="@style/yourStyle" in toolbar

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want to define the actionbar-style in the appTheme definition, and not in the toolbar element itself

Comment: Use <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</style> not